# InvalidUserPoolException in AWS AppSync

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync, aws-userpools

I have an AppSync API which runs a series of GraphQL queries/mutations. The sequence was working fine until it randomly threw a 500 error with this in the response header: `x-amzn-ErrorType=InvalidUserPoolException`. Additionally, there was a mutation before this request which never updated the DynamoDB data source it was attached to.

I don't understand why I would get the `InvalidUserPoolException` if the requests prior to this error worked fine with that userpool? And I don't know if this would be related to the mutation's failure to update the DynamoDB table? Everything works in our development environment but this is a failure in production.

Answer (score 1):

That error is thrown if in any way based on the configuration you provided related to your user pool, we cannot construct the well known endpoint corresponding to the user pool so I would verify the user pool format.

Comment: Thanks. It's just strange that the client was able to use the user pool config in the requests immediately before and after this error, like milliseconds before and after.